# 2D plot of position and angle in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, plot, 2d, draw

I have made a controller for a car and I am currently trying to make a GUI for the controller in Qt.
The only thing I am lacking now is a visualization of the car's position and angle relative to its starting point.

I want to make something like this:

[image]

where the circle represents the car and the line in it represents its heading/angle.

An added bonus feature would be to have a fading trace of its path as it moves, but if I got the basics down, I should be able to sort that out myself.

I have tried looking at some plot examples, but couldn't extrapolate what I needed to solve my problem.

How would you recommend going about the implementation of something like this?

Comment: Are you asking how to rotate an image in Qt? Or are you asking how to calculate angular momentum? If you're looking to calculate the angular momentum you'll need a *lot* of feed back from your car sensors. For example a compass sensor is your best bet, but it would have to stay level, and it doesn't work well in all situations. Near the pole, or on trips that exceed the longitude resolution of your sensor.

Comment: No, i have all the measurements. I am only interested in taking the position and heading data and creating a plot looking like the one in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691109/2d-plot-of-position-and-angle-in-qt?noredirect=1#comment60975150_36691109):

> I have all the measurements

So let's assume that you have [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) such that you can filter out changes in roll and only consider changes in φ.

To do this you'll be looking to extend a `QWidget` adding a member φ, we'll name it: `m_phi`. We'll also need to add your `QPixMap` as a member, we'll call it `m_px`. And you'll be overriding the [`QWidget::paintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

```
paintEvent(qPaintEvent* /*event*/) {        
    if(!m_px.isNull()) {
        QPainter* p;

        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        p.translate(width() / 2.0, height() / 2.0);
        p.save();
        p.rotate(m_phi);

        QRect r = m_px.rect();

        r.moveCenter(QPoint());
        p.drawPixmap(r, m_px);
        p.restore();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Is QPixMap an image i have to use as a background? If so, is it possible to just render a white background without having an actualy image of a white background? Sorry if the questions sounds stupid, but I am fairly new to Qt.

Comment: I tried editing my comment, but i was over the 5min limit. Would you mind adding this to a new widget project for me to run? I am fairly new to Qt, as i said, and I am not quite sure how to add this to my current project. I understand if it is too much to ask.

Comment: @trudesagen We're kinda getting outside the scope of the question here. You can see the code example that I extrapolated my code from here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53765-rotate-an-image?s=bdcf06102a97f1642ed73a3aa8321944&p=241416#post241416 Qt widgets are designed to be extended, so the farther you get into Qt the more familiar you'll find yourself with this kinda behavior. in the linked example `Widget` is the extension of `QWidget` in question. If you have more questions about extending, I'd encourage you to open a new question about that and I'll try to answer there.